# GNU Make "gsrc/%.v: %.rdl" file generation

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Hello I'm currently using GNU Make and one of my targets is as shown.

```
    gsrc/%.v: %.rdl
          run tool on the .rdl
```

The tool generates a gsrc/example.v, example.vh, and a example.xml file (normally into my current working directory).  The example.v file is moved into the gsrc directory off the target definition I'm assuming and I'm trying to figure out way for all of the files generated to be moved into the gsrc directory.

I guess firstly, does the gsrc/%.v cause the generated file to be moved to the gsrc directory, and if so how can I get my .vh and .xml into the same directory using make?

-Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make doesn't ever move any files anywhere.  If you write a rule like:

```
gsrc/%.v : %.rdl
        <run some command>
```

you're telling make that when it wants to build a file named `gsrc/example.v` it can execute `<run some command>` and that command will create and/or update that file.  The contents of that recipe *must* do all the updating and moving of files.  Make doesn't do it for you.

So, if you want your output to go into `gsrc` but the command you run doesn't put it there, then you can just add more stuff to your recipe to move it:

```
gsrc/%.v gsrc/%.vh gsrc/%.xml: %.rdl
        <run some command>
        mv $*.vh $*.xml gsrc
```

Comment: I should point out that if you're really picky about error handling there's a lot more you need to do, so that if things fail this rule cleans up properly.  But this will do 99% of what you want.

Comment: For completeness could you expand on what those extra things are?

Comment: It's hard to know without details of what the "some command" actually does, but maybe you will want to delete the outputs before running the command, like `rm -f gsrc/$*.v gsrc/$*.vh gsrc/$*.xml`.  Then the `mv` command could fail with only some of the files moved over, so if it fails you'd want to delete them all (but don't forget to still exit with an error code so make knows it didn't work).  And you may want to do some cleanup if "some command" fails but since we don't know what it does it's hard to be sure.